# How to pass username and password to an external GUI-based application

Tags: file, batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to auto schedule a GUI-based application (brokerage platform) in windows 10 using Task Scheduler. I need some help with writing the batch file (which I will auto schedule in the Task Scheduler later). I am able to fire up the application ....but how do I pass the username and password to the application in the batch file so the application starts on its own without user intervention? The application when started pops up a GUI window with the username and password fields.

I have tried some windows utilities and writing a batch file....but can't get it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by username/password? Is that to let your user automatically login into your application or something else?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to see if the application can accept parameters from the command line - yes, even if it is a GUI application.

A couple of approaches:
- Check the documentation (obviously)
- From the command prompt type "appname /?" and see if it responds with some information about the parameters that it accepts. If you are lucky, this will include username and password.

Otherwise you will really need to find out what methods the application supports to authenticate the user.

Scripting may be helpful after you find out that information.